# MySQL deadlock occurs in unique key when "replace into" statement is used

Tags: mysql, database, transactions, locking, b-tree

#### Summarize the problem

A deadlock problem occurs when the statement as "replace into model_test values(1, abc, 111)" and the statement as "replace into model_test values(2, abcd, 123)" execute at the same time in a multi-thread environment.

#### Show some codes

In the production environment, a table like this(simplification):

```
id name  value
1  abc   111
2  abcd  123
```

create table statement as:

```
CREATE TABLE `db_research`.`model_test` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `value` INT(11) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `name_UNIQUE` (`name` ASC));
```

When I execute `show engine innodb status`,we can see some information about "LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK"

#### Provide background including what you've alreadly tried

MySQL version : 8.0.11

I have tried to split `replace into` statement into `delete` statement and `insert` statement.

transaction2:

```
mysql>begin;
mysql>delete from model_test where id = 2;
Query OK,1 row affected(0.02 sec)
```

transaction1:

```
mysql>begin;
mysql>replace into model_test values(1,'abc',111);
(waiting...)
```

transaction2:

```
mysql>insert into model_test values(2,'abcd',123);
Query OK,1 row affected(0.08 sec)
```

transaction1:

```
ERROR 1213 (40001): Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

`show engine innodb status :`

```
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
LOCK WAIT 4 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 2
replace into model_test values(1,'abc','111')
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 3565 page no 4 n bits 72 index name_UNIQUE of table `db_research`.`model_test` trx id 1238711 lock_mode X waiting

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
5 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 4 row lock(s), undo log entries 2
insert into model_test values(2,'abcd','123')
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 3565 page no 4 n bits 72 index name_UNIQUE of table `db_research`.`model_test` trx id 1238710 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 3565 page no 4 n bits 72 index name_UNIQUE of table `db_research`.`model_test` trx id 1238710 lock mode S waiting

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

Is it due to MySQL's next-key lock on the unique key?

Comment: Did you COMMIT your transactions when they were completed? BEGIN must be matched with COMMIT or ROLLBACK or the locks get held.

Comment: Yes,I can commit the transaction2, but the transaction1 has been rolled back automatically due to the deadlock as you can see in `show engine innodb status`.

Comment: Yes, it does.To my confusion, it appears that the deadlock was caused by a lock resource on unique key as you can see in `show engine innodb status`